# Determining if there is a solution to a differential equation that has a stationary point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

We have the following differential equation:

$yf'_x+xf'_y=xy(x^2+y^2)$ where $x > 0$ and $y > 0$

We would like to check if there is a solution to the equation that has a stationary point in the first quadrant ($x>0$, $y>0$). So we do not want to solve this equation if there is such a solution, just prove whether such a solution exists or does not exist.

How do I approach this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by $f'_x$?

Comment: The derivative of $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out now.

If we have $yf'_x+xf'_y=xy(x^2+y^2)$ and take a look at the left hand side we can see that if we have a stationary point, the derivatives must be equal to $0$. Thus $yf'_x+xf'_y=0$ at the stationary point.

If we take a look at the right hand side, we said that the stationary point must be located in $x >0, y>0$. So this expression must be greater than $0$, $xy(x^2+y^2) > 0$.

Since the left side must be equal to $0$ and the right side is always greater than $0$ there is no such solution $f(x,y)$ such that it has a stationary point in $x >0, y>0$.